# which function should i use for reaching Android Crypto plugin?

Tags: java, android, frameworks, android-mediaplayer, drm

i have an android question.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mocoZ.png)

this image is DRM framework path

in java layer, which function should i use for reaching Android Crypto plugin?

what is starting function in java layer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the multimedia - handling API layer for Android:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaDrm.html

Examples here:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.media.MediaDrm

More information:

[How to instantiate a MediaDrm object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170252/how-to-instantiate-a-mediadrm-object)

[Decrypting widevine DRM protected video in android using MediaDrm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510294/decrypting-widevine-drm-protected-video-in-android-using-mediadrm)